# urllib.request 'Request' object has no attribute 'getcode' and read

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urllib3

I am getting error for `print` statement 
**'Request' object has no attribute 'getcode' and read**

```
sample = '[{{ "t": "{0}", "to": "{1}", "evs": "{2}", "fds": {3} }}]'

response = urllib.request.Request(REST_API_URL, sample.encode('utf-8'))

print("Response: HTTP {0} {1}\n".format(response.getcode(), response.read()))
```

Comment: that's because it doesn't!

Comment: Yes, can you please suggest its alternative ...

Comment: you have the answers below... but for future reference, you can just use `dir(o)` in your case `print(dir(response))`

Comment: Sure ! Thanks you !

Answer (score 2):

`urllib.request.Request` is the class that the `urllib.request` module uses to abstract a request. To make an HTTP request you should use `urllib.request.urlopen` instead:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(REST_API_URL, sample.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

the variable you named `response` is actually an instance of a `urllib.request.Request`. if you want a response you need to send the request first, and that is done using `urllib.request.urlopen()`.

BUT instead of figuring out how to use python urllib.request, I suggest you to try the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) module which is MUCH easier to use. For example you code can be expressed like so:

```
import requests
resp = requests.post(REST_API_URL, json=[{{ "t": "{0}", "to": "{1}", "evs": "{2}", "fds": {3} }}])
print("Response: HTTP {} {}".format(resp.statuscode, resp.content)
```